# Проблема с "змейкой"

Tags: python, tkinter

Пишу змейку. Есть фрагмент кода:

```
segments = []

def create_snake():
global snake,segments
snake = field.create_rectangle(20,20,40,40,fill = 'blue')
segments.append(snake)
def start():
    global score_1,apple
    field.move(snake, *(direction))
    if field.coords(snake) == field.coords(apple): # IF SNAKE'S EATEN AN APPLE
        score_1+=1
        score.config(text = 'Your score: {}. Best score: {}'.format(score_1,highscore))
        field.delete(apple)
        create_apple()
        create_segment()

def create_segment():
name=field.create_rectangle(*field.coords(snake), fill='white')
segments.append(name)
def move():
        field.coords(segments[-1],*(field.coords(segments[0])))
        field.after(200, move)
return move()
```

В итоге нужно, что бы когда змея жрала яблоко, создавался новый квадрат, который будет следовать за змеей. Пока в итоге выходит только сделат так, что бы последний сегмент следовал за первым. Как сделать так, что бы каждый сегмент следовал за сегмент, который был создан до него?

Comment: как я понимаю, `field.coords(segments[-1],*(field.coords(segments[0])))`, здесь вы как раз и берете последний сегмент, и говорите ему, что "нужно следовать за первым". А вам, вероятно, надо в цикле пробежаться по всем сегментам, и обновить координаты каждого сегмента на координаты предыдущего. Думаю, суть понятна)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Comment: Для будущих поколений, пишущих змейку: при движении достаточно удалять последний сегмент и добавлять новую голову (в момент съедания "яблока" последний сегмент просто не удаляем), пересчитывать координаты всех сегментов не нужно.